# Finding the key of an array based on string match in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array[0] = 'House';
$array[1] = 'Condo';
$array[2] = 'Townhouse';
$array[3] = 'Land';
```

If I passed a var which contains either "condo" or "Condo" (in other words, case-insensitive), I want to return 1, indicating that $array[1] matches "condo" or "Condo" or "CONDO".

So basically I want:

```
$search = 'Condo';
$key = get_property_key($search, $array);
// $key should return 1
```

Is there a quick PHP method to do this? Or do I need to write my own function to loop through? If it's the latter, you don't need to write out the function for me - I can handle it myself. But I'm hoping there's a PHP function that I missed during my "education" period (although this education period NEVER ends).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in for case-insensitive search, but this works, based on plain old [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
 array_search(strtolower($search),array_map('strtolower',$array));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_search`, though that's case sensitive.  For an non-case sensitive `array_search`, you could do something like this:

```
function get_property_key($needle, $haystack){
    return array_search(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}
```

Comment: Yup Michael beat you by a minute.. same thing really. Gave you +1 anyway thanks so much, you guys rock.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

```
    foreach($array as $i){
        if(strtolower($i) == strtolower($query)){
            //do something
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That would search the value, not the key. If you had $a=>$i in the foreach line this may work. However the above solutions with array_key() function was the more elegant & simpler solution.

Comment: @jeffkee but arent you searching for the value.. i.e. Condo.. and not the key?

Comment: No, as the question clearly states, I need the $key: "$key should return 1"

Answer (score -1):

There's no built in function; you'd have to roll your own.  I'm not sure if this will suit your needs but on approach about be to index the array with the lower cased version and then look for $array[strtolower($search))]

Comment: apparently array_search() is a function.

Answer (score -1):

Why not populate the array with key names for the value you are searching, normalized so it's always lowercase :

```
$array['condo'] = true;
$array['land']  = true;
//and so on

//and then the search becomes really fast
if (isset($array[strtolower($search)])) {
  //element found
}
```